# Java Servlet on Tomcat called from AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, servlets, tomcat7, url-mapping

I want to call a Servlet from ajax in a Java WebApp, using Tomcat7.

I used the annotation @WebServlet("/VServlet") to mapping it in the WebApp, because of Tomcat7 support Servlet 3.0.
I call the servlet with the jquery command "$.getJSON('VServlet', function(data){ ... });" but if I use the string 'VServlet', it doesn't work.

Only if I use the entire url 'http:// localhost:8080/WebAppName/VServlet' it works, but only in my pc. However I have to deploy it on a server that has a commercial domain name, obviously different from "localhost".

Please, can anyone tell me if there is a way to address the servlet with a relative url?
Because if I use a string like 'http://my.domain.it:8080/WebAppName/VServlet' it doesn't work on the Tomcat7 that is on the server machine.

Thanks.

------------------EDIT-----------------------

I try to explain better my problem.
I have a Java Servlet that return a json structure. The servlet is called in a javascript file that have to draw a graph in a web page, building a SVG image. I have to deploy this web app on a commercial Windows server with Tomcat7 installed.
The web app generally works. Any errors are displayed from the user point of view. Simply the image doesn't appear if I use that strings I wrote above, to call the servlet.
I suppose that the servlet doesn't respond because I use a wrong address/naming. If I use an absolute url, the servlet responds to the js caller, but I need a relative string, so if the domain name of the server will change, I won't change the code of the js file too.

Comment: It is a suggestion, is not the answer. Have you heard of DWR? URL: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
$.getJSON('VServlet', ... );
```

you are making a HTTP GET request to an *URL relative to the current URL*. That is, if you're in `/webapp/users/user.xhtml` you'll be sending a request to `/webapp/users/VServlet` which obviously doesn't match the URL pattern of your servlet and not the thing you're trying to achieve.

You need to take into account the context path of a JSF application that's available in view as `#{request.contextPath}` to build up a *proper absolute URL*:

```
$.getJSON('#{request.contextPath}/VServlet', ... );
```

This will send a request to `http://localhost:8080/webapp/VServlet`.

In case you need to send request to a path relative to the root, such request URLs start with a slash, `/` and represent *URLs relative to the root*, no matter where you're right now:

```
$.getJSON('/VServlet', ... );
```

This will send a request to `http://localhost:8080/VServlet`.

Comment: This sends a request to `http://localhost:8080/VServlet`, not to `http://localhost:8080/WebAppName/VServlet` as OP intented.

Comment: @user2042895 See the answer update. As BalusC rightfully stated in his comment to this question, in the answer I forgot to take into account the context of your web application.

Comment: I used `/WebAppName/VServelt` as @BalusC and you suggest, but it doesn't still not work on the server. It works only locally on my pc. Which string I have to use in the commercial server?

Comment: It's perhaps helpful if you elaborate "doesn't work" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. "Doesn't work" is in this context less or more interpreted as "It returns HTTP response code 404" although you never explicitly stated that as being a real web developer in the question. Is this assumption true? Or are you actually hitting some CORS border? Please look in the HTTP traffic monitor and JS console for clues.

Answer (score 0):

if your js code is inside jsp page Instead of the code

$.getJSON('VServlet', function(data){ ... });

write

"$.getJSON('${request.contextPath}/VServlet', function(data){ ... });

other wise if this code is in some js file in a function something like

```
function someFunction(){
     $.getJSON('VServlet', function(data){ ... });
}
```

and you are calling function someFunction() from jsp
then you add a parameter to the function like this -

```
function someFunction(url){
         $.getJSON('VServlet', function(data){ ... });
    }
```

and now call it from jsp like this -

someFunction('${request.contextPath}/VServlet')

because ${request.contextPath}/VServlet is an el tag and it will get compiled only in jsp page